# Adjust the size of folium popups

Tags: python, pandas, leaflet, folium

| Site_Number | Site_Description | Region_Site | Latitude | Longitude | S1_AverageSpeed | S1_85thSpeed | S2_AverageSpeed | S2_85thSpeed | S3_AverageSpeed | S3_85thSpeed | String_for_Popup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0 | A6093 | Pencaitland, A6093 (Site 1) | 55.91 | -2.89 | 25.15 | 30.07 | 25.78 | 30.55 | NaN | NaN | **Site Number:** 1.0 **Description:** A6093 **S1 Average Speed:** 25.15 **S1 85th %ile Speed:** 30.07 **S2 Average Speed:** 25.78 **S2 85th %ile Speed:** 30.55 **S3 Average Speed:** nan **S3 85th %ile Speed:** nan ' |
| 2.0 | B1345 Main Road | Dirleton, B1345 Main Road (Site 2) | 56.05 | -2.78 | 23.14 | 28.23 | 23.0 | 28.54 | 22.04 | 26.72 | **Site Number:** 2.0 **Description:** B1345 Main Road **S1 Average Speed:** 23.14 **S1 85th %ile Speed:** 28.23 **S2 Average Speed:** 23.0 **S2 85th %ile Speed:** 28.54 **S3 Average Speed:** 22.04 **S3 85th %ile Speed:** 26.72 |
| 3.0 | Main Road | Macmerry, Main Road (Site 3) | 55.94 | -2.91 | 29.72 | 34.05 | 26.88 | 32.4 | NaN | NaN | **Site Number:** 3.0 **Description:** Main Road **S1 Average Speed:** 29.72 **S1 85th %ile Speed:** 34.05 **S2 Average Speed:** 26.88 **S2 85th %ile Speed:** 32.4 **S3 Average Speed:** nan **S3 85th %ile Speed:** nan |

I am working with a table like the one above, and I have written code to plot each set of latitudes and longitudes with the popup set to equal the popup string which contains pre-formatted HTML strings.

```
map = folium.Map(location=[new_df.Latitude.mean(), new_df.Longitude.mean()], zoom_start=12, control_scale=True,min_zoom=10,max_zoom=12)

for index, location_info in new_df.iterrows():
    folium.Marker([location_info["Latitude"], location_info["Longitude"]], popup=location_info["String_for_Popup"], tooltip=location_info["Site_Description"]).add_to(map)
```

This does manage to plot all the points with the correct popup, however the size of the popup message is too narrow and so splits the string over multiple lines as seen in the picture below:

[image]

Is there a way to adjust the width of the popups so that each value can fit on its own line?

Comment: As shown in the answer, you can modify it as follows. `folium.Marker([location_info["Latitude"], location_info["Longitude"]], popup=folium.Popup(location_info["String_for_Popup"], max_width=300, min_width=300), tooltip=location_info["Site_Description"]).add_to(map)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is example that worked for me:

```
fgroup.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[39.28173017251679, -74.5628182419811],
popup=folium.Popup("Golfing, Jetskiing and surfing", max_width=300,min_width=300),
icon=folium.Icon(color='red')))
```

Comment: What exact code did you use? I get the following error unfortunately: NameError: name 'fgroup' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I added the following, I hope this example helps you

```
  folium.Marker(
location=[lat, long],
popup=folium.Popup(f"<h5>{rec_type}</h5>{caption}", max_width=300,min_width=300),
icon=folium.Icon(color=test, icon=icon,prefix=prefix)).add_to(m)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).